# Constraints don't work on UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, autolayout, constraints

In my application, there are three '`UICollectionViews`'. If I set `constraints` to them, they make something strange... The '`UICollectionViews`' get melted together and only one of them is displayed and the `UICollectionViewCells` don't get stretched when the screen is bigger (iPad/ iPhone +).

Is there anything special I have to consider when using constraints on the '`UICollectionViews`'?

Here's a picture to make it more clear what I mean:

[image]

[image]

Comment: to what items are trailing and leading constraints of collection views equal?

Comment: I haven't set any constraints yet because what I did didn't work. I want that there are 48 items in the left CV and 12 in the two others

Comment: This looks like your question from a month ago -- but you didn't follow-up on it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53297580/collectionviews-move-weird-when-setting-constraints

Comment: I tried everything but since I'm a new coder I don't know if I managed to do it the right way

Comment: @SWIFTstuff - The way you are showing this, set appropriate Width constraints on each collection view. If that doesn't do it, you need to be a little more clear on what you're trying to do. Show an image of how you want it to look on an iPhone *and* on an iPad... and how you want it to look in Landscape orientation (if different).

Comment: @DonMag I want it to look like the picture which I added on iPhone and on iPad. If I set width constraints, the cells would have the same width on every device. I want that the cells get bigger if the screen would allow that but there should be only four cells in a row.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like cell size & view size mismatch, because you didn't mentioned about the cell.

In that case, make an outlet of Collection View Flow Layout and adjust the cell size accordingly.

```
@IBOutlet weak var collView: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var collLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout!

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    var w = self.view.frame.width
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        w = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame.width
    }
    let padding:CGFloat = 20
    let spacing:CGFloat = 5
    let columns:CGFloat = 6
    let cw = ceil((w - padding) / columns)
    collLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: cw - spacing*2, height: cw - spacing*2)
    collLayout.minimumLineSpacing = spacing
    collLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = spacing

    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
}
```

Comment: I added this part to my code and got this error : 2018-12-11 15:25:55.156018+0100 MastermindProjekt[8501:144983] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UICollectionView setItemSize:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7faf8e84c400'

Comment: How do I have to connect the UICollectionViewFlowLayout?